# Unmodified column name index in patsy

Tags: python, machine-learning, patsy

I am using patsy to prepare categorical data for regression and want to map from a column name to its index in the `DesignMatrix`. I have tried using the `column_name_indexes` attribute of the [`DesignInfo`](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#patsy.DesignInfo) object but the column names have been modified to reflect the encoding.

Example using data from the [docs](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html):

```
>>> from patsy import demo_data, dmatrix
>>> data = demo_data("a", nlevels=3)
>>> data
{'a': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3']}

>>> x = dmatrix("a", data)
>>> x
DesignMatrix with shape (6, 3)
  Intercept  a[T.a2]  a[T.a3]
          1        0        0
          1        1        0
          1        0        1
          1        0        0
          1        1        0
          1        0        1
  Terms:
    'Intercept' (column 0)
    'a' (columns 1:3)

>>> x.design_info.column_name_indexes
OrderedDict([('Intercept', 0), ('a[T.a2]', 1), ('a[T.a3]', 2)])
```

I would like to be able to access the column index of e.g. `'a2'` by calling:

```
x.design_info.column_name_indexes['a2']
```

But of course that returns `KeyError: 'a2'`.  So instead I have to construct the modified key myself in order to obtain the desired column index `1`:

```
x.design_info.column_name_indexes['a[T.a2]']
```

Is there a way to access the column index by referring to the unmodified feature/column name, i.e. `'a2'` rather than having to construct the modified key, i.e. `'a[T.a2]'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no one-to-one mapping between categorical values like `a2` and design matrix columns. The column you're talking about is already more complicated than that -- it's a treatment contrast between the `a2` and `a1` values -- and things can be arbitrarily more complicated than that (e.g. consider Helmert or polynomial coding).

If you know that you want to look up the treatment contrast associated with `a2` of the variable `a`, then you can use

```
def column_for_treatment(design_info, factor, value):
    column_name = "{}[T.{}]".format(factor, value)
    return design_info.column_name_indexes[colum_name]

column_for_treatment(x.design_info, "a", "a2")
```

It's a bit silly-looking, but it should work, and I'm not sure what would be better given the general problems mentioned above.